# Reading PUT data from piped cURL in Sinatra

Tags: curl, request, sinatra, pipe, put

I'm rewriting a small server backend in Sinatra, and currently the client talks to it via cURL calls such as `echo "foo" | curl -X PUT -T - http://localhost:8090/`. The problem is, in my `put` method in Sinatra, the `request.body.read` is always empty, even after I call `rewind` on it. Furthermore, the `params` hash is completely empty.

What's weird is that if I do `curl -X PUT -d 'foo' http://localhost:8090/` instead it works. Also, in node.js I can read it fine using the `request.on('data')` and `request.on('end')` functions.

Is there any way to read the `PUT` body in Sinatra? I would like to avoid changing the client code if at all possible.

Comment: Are you using `request.body`, or `request.body.read`? The latter is the correct syntax for reading the body of a `POST` request.

Comment: @KyleLacy Yes I'm using `request.body.read`. Updated the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the curl command from the client is misusing the `-T` flag.  `-T` is for uploading a file, not sending data. Normally, when you don't provide a destination file name, `-T` will use the local file name for the upload.  For example, `curl -X PUT -T "bar.txt" http://localhost:8090/` will upload the local file `bar.txt` to the remote location `http://localhost:8090/bar.txt`. Since your client code pipes stdin instead of specifying a file, no local file name exists. And since your client code does not specify any destination file name, it will produce undefined results. I would consider it non-standard behavior for node.js to accept the contents of a file upload as data in the request body.

Your second example using the `-d` flag is the proper way to send data. I really think the best solution would be to change the client code, but you can still pipe stdin if you want to. Just use `-d` instead of `-T`, like so:

```
echo "foo" | curl -X PUT -d @- http://localhost:8090/
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Although you have to use `--data-binary` instead of `-d` if you want curl to upload the data as-is (preserve newlines etc). Also, the curl man page is confusing on `-T` - it says you can use `-T -` "to use stdin instead of a given file". I suppose they meant piping in the file _name instead of the file _contents_?

Comment: Yeah, the man page is a little vague. My understanding is that `-T -` causes curl to accept stdin as the *contents* of the file to upload, so the destination file must be specified. For example: `echo "foo" | curl -X PUT -T - http://localhost:8090/bar` should result in the creation of `bar` at the destination with "foo" as the contents.